# Where to use the API authorisation key in this API?

Tags: api, request, authorization

I am working with the following api:

https://www.football-data.org/documentation/api

I have gotten myself an api key and I tried to make the example request:

```
https://api.football-data.org/v2/teams/86/matches?status=SCHEDULED
```

of course I get the error

```
{"message":"The resource you are looking for is restricted. Please pass a valid API token and check your subscription for permission.","errorCode":403}
```

So the question is, is how do I give the website my api key to allow me to make these requests?

Looking at the python snippet they create a dictionary with the the api key as a value and pass that to the request. How can I make this in my browser?

I tried

```
https://api.football-data.org/v2/teams/86/matches?status=SCHEDULED&%22X-Auth-Token%22=%22MYAPIKEY%22
```

and it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing your API key as a query parameter, which is not in line with the API specification.
The API needs the key as an HTTP header. You cannot easily do that in a web browser. I'd suggest getting something like [Postman](https://go.postman.co/network/import?collection=408fdabf81ced6dda1b0&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.football-data.org%2Fdocumentation%2Fquickstart) or to do it on the command-line:

```sh
curl -i -H "X-Auth-Token: MYAPIKEY" "https://api.football-data.org/v2/teams/86/matches?status=SCHEDULED"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have figured it out by now, but I am dropping this for anyone else looking on how to do it in Python:

```py
import requests
from pprint import pprint


token = "" # Write the api key emailed to you here

headers = {
    'X-Auth-Token': token,
}

r = requests.get('http://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/EC/teams', headers=headers).json()

pprint(r, indent=2, depth=1, compact=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using postman like @[Jakob Löhnertz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9480567/jakob-l%C3%B6hnertz) suggested.

1. You want to first enter the api

[image]

2. Then go over to the Headers tab, put in "X-Auth-Token" as your Key and your unique API token as your value. Hit send and you should be all good.

[image]

Finally, be sure to go through [here](https://www.football-data.org/coverage) to see the list of available competitions for a free account.